# OleDb Excel File doesn't save until close the application

Tags: c#, .net, excel, oledb

My application writes some data to excel file(2007) via OleDb. I am reading values from SQL Server and write to Excel file. It workings correctly. But excel file doesn't save until close the application.

I'm using using{} block both OleDbConnection and SqlConnection. I don't think it is a Dispose issue.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you please show your code?

Comment: have you closed the stream?

Comment: Is there a stream? I am using OleDbConncetion. Is it a stream? How can I close the stream?